# How do I use a non-maven project as a resource for my Maven module?

Tags: java, git, maven, mercurial

I need to use a non-Maven project (simply a folder with script files) from a remote hg repo as a resource for my Maven project in git. I need to use those files in my Java code.

What is the way to add them to my project it without:
 - Having to fork a non-maven repo
 - Having to make that project into Maven project
 - Having to move either project to a different repo

There must be some Maven plugin that lets adding archives to a project but I just cannot google it.

Comment: you want to add them as an archive, let's say a `zip` or a `jar`? would that be fine?

Comment: @A_Di-Matteo Yes that'd be fine

Answer (score 0):

What I needed is maven-scm-plugin that uses execution to clone a project from a different repo:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>checkout</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <basedir>${project.build.directory}</basedir>
                <checkoutDirectory>${project.build.directory}</checkoutDirectory>
                <connectionUrl>scm:hg:http://link-to-required-repo</connectionUrl>
                <username>www</username>
                <password>qqq</password>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```